# Fit multiple images on to a container, responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I know there are lots of posts with similar questions, but after reading them, I have not been able to solve my problem. I want a unique CSS solution for this.

This is my code:

```
    #infobox {
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
        width: 70%;
        .pics {
            opacity: 0.5;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

However, using this code, I have three pictures in a row and the fourth drops under these images. How could I adapt the size of these images in order to keep all them in just a row?

Comment: It is not possible to nest multiple rules, using normal CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that you only have 4 pictures by row you can use :

```
#infobox {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 70%;

}
#infobox .pics {
    opacity: 0.5;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: In this you should just keep in mind that if any padding or marigin is to be added between these images, the structure will break. Also, I don't know if the floating is what you should be doing here. I'd rather go with `display: inline-block` and maybe mess around a bit with `position` attribute.